# Как использовать ArrayList с кастомным классом в другом методе текущего класса?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Есть класс для ArrayList **ItemClass**. Есть ArrayList **nomenclatureList**, созданный в onCreate.

```
ArrayList<ItemClass> nomenclatureList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Хочу использовать Collections.sort(nomenclatureList) **за пределами** onCreate (внутри onCreate он прекрасно работает).

Если конкретно - хочу использовать Collections.sort(nomenclatureList) в контекстном меню:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_filter, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.alexeevskoe:
                Intent alexeevskoeMK = new Intent(ItemsListMK.this, AlexeevskoeMK.class);
                startActivity(alexeevskoeMK);
                break;
            case R.id.gustiyar:
                Intent gustiyarMK = new Intent(ItemsListMK.this, GustiyarMK.class);
                startActivity(gustiyarMK);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Код `onCreate`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.nomenclature_list);
nomenclatureList.add(new ItemClass(

[...]

ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, nomenclatureList);
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.nomenclature_list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Что мне необходимо использовать? Недавно в java и android, вероятно мой вопрос нубский, но не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявить `nomenclatureList` глобально в теле класса вашей `Activity`.

```
public class  MyActivity extends Activity {

     ArrayList<ItemClass> nomenclatureList = new ArrayList<>();
     ItemAdapter adapter;
     public void onCreate(...) {
          // что-то делаем с nomenclatureList 

          setContentView(R.layout.nomenclature_list);
          nomenclatureList.add(new ItemClass());

          [...]

          adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, nomenclatureList);
          ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.nomenclature_list);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Collections.sort(nomenclatureList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.alexeevskoe:
                Intent alexeevskoeMK = new Intent(ItemsListMK.this, AlexeevskoeMK.class);
                startActivity(alexeevskoeMK);
                break;
            case R.id.gustiyar:
                Intent gustiyarMK = new Intent(ItemsListMK.this, GustiyarMK.class);
                startActivity(gustiyarMK);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82130/discussion-on-answer-by-suvitruf---arraylist---).